# How would I fix this error "0curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server"

Tags: python, pyenv

When I run `command -v pyenv && pyenv update || curl https://pyenv.run | bash`

I end up getting the error `0curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server`

How would I go and fix this? [(Also I have attached a screenshot of what happens)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aW9g.png)

Comment: is curl blocked by your firewall/

Comment: Is this your local computer? Can you open  `https://pyenv.run` in web browser? Did you try directly `curl https://pyenv.run` ? If you run it on external server then it can be blocked to access external servers - to stop spamers/hackers/bots.

Comment: Curl might be blocked by my firewall, Im not sure though if it is or isnt

And this is not my local computer its a server and when i do "curl https://pyenv.run" I still receive the error

Comment: What ablout `ping pyenv.run`? and `curl -vvv https://pyenv.run`?

Comment: Both dont seem to work, I did ping and it said network is unreachable and I did curl and it gave me the original error

Comment: Sounds like the connection is the issue. You could try with wget instead. But it sounds like it is your connection that is the issue.:

`command -v pyenv && pyenv update ||  wget -O - -o /dev/null https://pyenv.run | bash`

Can you reach google.com for example?

Comment: Yeah Im able to reach google.com if I ping it, And when I run the command you typed I dont receive an error, But I also dont receive an output so I dont think it worked

Comment: Page don't seems to be working for you, if you are on a public cloud/organization your IP-address could have been black-listed. If that is the case, you have to change ip or wait until they de-blacklist you. Anyway might be worth a shot to try: `curl -s -S -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash` direct, since that is what you are trying to execute with your command.

Comment: That didnt seem to work, I found that the issue seems to be that the SELinux status is disabled, I have tried a couple things to enable it but nothing has seemed to work